# Promise returns array of strings, bat later in the code it is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, async-await, promise

So I have a submit handler, that is supposed to fetch some presigned URLS for image uploading, and then upload the images, and then continue on with submitting another final request. The outline of it all looks like this:

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
  try {
    const presignedUrls = await getPresignedUrls(someData)
    console.log(presignedUrls) -> // ['someUrl.png', 'someUrl2.png', ...]

    const arrayOfRequests = getUploadRequests(someData, presignedUrls)
    await Promise.all(arrayOfRequests)

    console.log(presignedUrls) -> // []
    await postData({ ...someData, imageUrls: presignedUrls })

  } catch (error) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Everything works fine, and it does everything in the correct order, but the problem is that I want to include the presignedUrls that I used in the final post request, but for some reason that array is empty when I try to access it again later on.

I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

All right so while writing this question I found out my stupid mistake (guess SO is great for rubber ducking as well  ), but I figured I'd post it anyways. The problem was that inside `getUploadRequests()` I mapped corresponding image data together with the presigned url from the `presignedUrls` array, and once I had used one url, I sliced the array to remove that url form the array, without having made a new temporary array, so the object reference was still pointing to the same array, hence, the array was empty once I had used all the presigned urls.

Fixed by either spreading in the urls to `getUploadRequests(someData, [...presignedUrls])` or by creating a new array inside `getUploadRequests()` with the urls.

Time for some vacation I believe.